# yarn dev does not finish building plugin

Tags: grafana, grafana-plugin

I’m following the [Grafana tutorial for buiding a new plugin](https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin/) (running Grafana v9.2.2
Node v16.18.1) but `yarn dev` is stuck at "No errors found." Here's the complete output.

> 

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack -w -c ./.config/webpack/webpack.config.ts --env development
<i> [LiveReloadPlugin] Live Reload listening on port 35729
assets by path *.md 161 bytes
  asset README.md 109 bytes [emitted] [from: README.md] [copied]
  asset CHANGELOG.md 52 bytes [emitted] [from: ../CHANGELOG.md] [copied]
asset module.js 16.3 KiB [emitted] (name: module)
asset LICENSE 11.1 KiB [emitted] [from: ../LICENSE] [copied]
asset img/logo.svg 1.55 KiB [emitted] [from: img/logo.svg] [copied]
asset plugin.json 789 bytes [emitted] [from: plugin.json] [copied]
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
built modules 2.7 KiB [built]
  cacheable modules 2.53 KiB
    ./module.ts 1.04 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./components/SimplePanel.tsx 1.49 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path external "@grafana/ 84 bytes
    external "@grafana/data" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external "@grafana/ui" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  external "react" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  external "@emotion/css" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.75.0 compiled successfully in 2031 ms
Type-checking in progress...
assets by status 29.9 KiB [cached] 6 assets
cached modules 2.7 KiB (javascript) 937 bytes (runtime) [cached] 10 modules
webpack 5.75.0 compiled successfully in 574 ms
Type-checking in progress...
No errors found.
```

While I was trying to solve this issue, I've found the repo [grafana-toolkit (also from Grafana)](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/packages/grafana-toolkit), with a different set of instructions to build a plugin. In this case, `yarn dev` runs without a problem.

However it appears that grafana/toolkit is going to be deprecated and the correct way to build plugins is to use grafana/create-plugin (i.e. following the first set of instructions). Therefore I still have to solve my initiall problem. Any ideas?